# How do I get tabbed content to 'push' other page content down instead of overlaying?

Tags: html, css

I have some tabbed content. It all works beautifully except I need it to 'push' down my page when it's height exceeds that of the page it is contained within.

You can see the problem [here](http://www.jellypit.com.au/test) when you click on tab 3.
Is there some kind of easy fix for this without me needing to change other layout of my website?
I *can* make it work by adding 
 statements to the page the tabbed content is in, but this really isn't a workable solution.

This is the html to show the tabbed content. Note the "br" statements so tab 1 and tab2 content doesn't overlap the rest of my page.

```
<ul class="tabs">
            <li>
              <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1">
              <label for="tab1">tab 1</label>
              <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
               This is ok
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">
              <label for="tab2">tab 2</label>
              <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
                    This is ok too.
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3">
              <label for="tab3">tab 3</label>
              <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
                "This isn't ok :( But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of     denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
              </div>
            </li>
        </ul>


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Here is the css:

```
.tabs input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}
.tabs {
  width: 650px;
  float: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 75px auto;
  background-color: grey;
}
.tabs li{
  float: left;
}
.tabs label {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    color: #08C;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'Roboto', helveti;
    background: grey;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.tabs label:hover {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  top: 0;
}

[id^=tab]:checked + label {
  background: #08C;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
}

[id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content] {
    display: block;
}
.tab-content{
 /* z-index: 2;*/
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 140%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: #08C;
  padding: 15px;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 53px;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `overflow:hidden` to the `.tabs`.

Example:

```
.tabs {
  width: 650px;
  float: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 75px auto;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to give that a go right now...

Bummer, that didn't work. Only displayed the tabs and the content dissapeared.

Answer (score 0):

Height needs px to be a valid rule. However, you don't want to hardcode the height on something like this.

```
#tab_container {
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 500;
}
```